# Select distinct column from table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have the database structure as shown in the below image:

I want to retrieve `variant_id` that belongs to particular `product_id`

Example :

lets say 1 and `Size = L` , `Color = Green`.

I expect mysql query to return variant_id = 7.

**What is the expected query to be used in this scenario?**

[image: Database Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following query.
I'm assuming your table name is `table1`

```
select variant_id from (select * from table1 where 
product_id=1 and ((attribute_name='Size' and value='L')
or (attribute_name='Color' and value='Green'))) as temp 
group by variant_id having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. It works like charm. You made my day